# Garbage values in pointer array

Tags: c, local-variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(int **);

int main()
{

  int *arr[2];

  func(arr);

  printf("value [1] = %d \n",*arr[0]);

  printf("value [2] = %d \n",*arr[1]);
  return 0;
}

void func(int **arr)
{
  int j = 10;
  arr[0] = &j;
  arr[1] = &j;
}
```

The code gets compiled successfully with gcc. However, the output is:

```
value [1] = 10 

value [2] = 32725
```

The second value is a garbage value. Why is it so? How can i use double pointer correctly to access an array?

Comment: It is illegal to use local variable from some function (`j` from `func`) after this function exit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is **[Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**.
You are storing address of a local variable `j` which does not exist beyond the function.
`j` is guaranteed to live only within the function scope `{ }`. Referring to `j` through its address once this scope ends results in Undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior means that the compiler is not needed to show any particular observed behavior and hence it can show any output.

Comment: and what about "auto storage class" (storage duration)?

Comment: @osgx: What about it? I am sorry I do not understand.

Comment: Alok, there is no words "local variable" in some pdf files... e.g. in this file: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf. Why you think than taking address of smth what you called "local variable" is undefined behavior?

Comment: @osgx: The variables with storage class `auto` are commonly known as local or automatic variables. Automatic since they do not need any explicit cleaning. Though these are not standerdese terminology these are commonly and widely used.

Comment: I mean ISO/IEC 9899 "section 6.2.4 paragraph 2,4,5" which actually defines undefined behavior for this case.

Comment: @AlokSave - Thanks.I understood what you said.However I am just curious even in undefined behavior why every time on executing this program,it correctly prints the first value.any idea?

Comment: @bornfree: Once an undefined behavior happens all bets are off so the first value may or may not be same. It is same in your case because the memory address is probably left untouched till it is being accessed. Note that the variable does not live beyond the scope doesnt't mean its value get erased explicitly. It merely gets marked for reuse so if that address gets reused again the content there will be removed if not the content still stays same. This is because explicitly deleting content at every such address would hit the performance. So the content is removed on reuse.

Answer (score 0):

```
int j=10;
```

is a local variable allocated on stack. Dereferencing it outside the function is undefined behaviour.
**WARNING:** Never ever return a pointer to any local variable unless you are pretty sure what you are doing. If you are sure, think about it again.

Comment: Is there any case when returning address of local variable is legal?

Comment: @phoeagon - I am just curious even in undefined behavior why every time on executing this program,it correctly prints the first value.any idea?

Comment: Undefined behaviour means compiler can implement whatever they want, it does not necessarily means the runtime behaviour will be different each time you execute it.